# Math related: How do I get a different scale if the value is less than one or greater than one

Tags: actionscript-3, math, flex4, scale

This should be an easy to solve but my brain has been fried the last few days. I have a slider that zooms in and zooms out a image. I want to zoom into the pixel level and zoom out to the pixel level but I **have** to have the thumbnail button be centered in the slider for a scale of 1.

What I have now is,

In code:
// if the scale value is 1 the image is shown at original size
var scale:Number = zoomSlider.value/1000;
sprite.scaleX = sprite.scaleY = scale;

I set the default value to 5000 *so that* the button is centered in the middle but that sets the scale to 5. What I want is when I drag left (from the initial value of 5000) it should start to scale down until it gets to the minimum scale of .10. When I drag right it should start to increase the scale to 10.

The key to this question is that I **have** to have the thumbnail button centered in the middle of the slider and when centered the scale is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the scale for 0 to 10,000 (since you specified center to be 5000) as above, then use

```
var scale:Number = zoomSlider.value/5000; 
sprite.scaleX    = sprite.scaleY = scale;
```

Whatever be the **Scale**, To keep the **Scale Button** centered and **Image** scaled to 1, set the **'scale'** variable to 1/2 of the max **Scale** value.